# CocoaPods update , due to capacitor error. Need advice

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am working on a Ionic Capacitor project. Previously i had capacitor version 2 installed, but a new update for @capacitor-community/bluetooth-le, required Capacitor 3.

But i have now updated to Capacitor 3, but when i do a sync , i am getting the following error message

```
update ios - failed!
[error] Analyzing dependencies
        [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Capacitor":
        In Podfile:
        Capacitor (from `../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios`)
        
        Specs satisfying the `Capacitor (from `../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios`)` dependency were found, but they
        required a higher minimum deployment target.
        
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
        
      capacitor sync exited with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Why don't you generate Podfile again ? If you generate a new Podfile, the new version of Capacitor will be written automatically inside Podfile. I'm using Capacitor 3 and have no problem with pod 'Capacitor' inside Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [Capacitor upgrade guide?](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#set-ios-deployment-target-to-120)

Seems like your required target is lower than expected. Minimum for Capacitor 3 is 12. You have to upgrade both in XCode project and the pod file, as described in the link.